# Umbraco: What can I do to fix my stream content with Multiple Node Tree Picker?

Tags: .net, xslt, umbraco6

I'm looking for a correct way to use the 'Multiple Node Tree Picker'. I installed the package, created a data type with it, then I wrote a Macro and I can use the drag and drop feature to choose what pages I want to show in the Homepage (from the Featured Articles Section of my website), but it doesn't show anything. Clearly, I've did something wrong in the Macro (XSLT), I don't know so much about XSLT. Thanks.

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/articlePicker/MultiNodePicker/nodeId"> 
      <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/articlePicker/MultiNodePicker/nodeId"> 
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1144)" /> 
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(.)}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$node/@nodeName" /> 
        </a> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your XSLT here, otherwise it's not that easy to guess where the problem is

Comment: Thank you, @Jk1 , there is it. So, I want to get content from a subnode called 'Editorial' (the route is Inicio/Secciones/Editorial), but I don't find out the way. Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

try this .....

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:if test="count($currentPage/articlePicker/MultiNodePicker/nodeId) &gt; 0"> 
      <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/articlePicker/MultiNodePicker/nodeId"> 
        <xsl:variable name="node" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(current())" /> 
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($node)}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$node/@nodeName" /> 
        </a> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```